Celery idempotent periodic task - cancel previous instances of task before running the new one
I'm using Celery 5 for task scheduling in my application, with tasks configured to run periodically every 10 minutes. However, I've encountered an issue where, due to server downtime or a backlog in the task queue, multiple instances of the same periodic task might be queued or running simultaneously. I want to ensure that only the latest instance of a periodic task runs, and any previous instances are canceled if they haven't started yet.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
   
    
    from celery import Celery
    from celery.schedules import crontab
    
    app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
    
    @app.task
    def my_periodic_task():
        print("Running periodic task")
        # Simulate a long-running task
        time.sleep(30)
        print("Task completed")
    
    @app.on_after_configure.connect
    def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
        # Executes every 10 minutes
        sender.add_periodic_task(
            crontab(minute='*/10'),
            my_periodic_task.s(),
        )

What I need is a way to:
Ensure only the latest instance of my_periodic_task runs as they are idempotent
Cancel any previous instances of the task if they are still in the queue or running.

You can use a simple task check to ensure that only the latest task is executed, and previous tasks are effectively ignored or canceled.

from celery import shared_task
from celery.task.control import revoke
import time

# Maintain a global variable to track the latest task
latest_task_id = None

@shared_task(bind=True)
def my_periodic_task(self):
    global latest_task_id
    task_id = self.request.id

    if latest_task_id:
        # Revoke the previous task if it's still running
        revoke(latest_task_id, terminate=True)

    latest_task_id = task_id

    # Simulate task logic
    print("Running my_periodic_task")
    time.sleep(10)  # Simulate long-running task

In this example, latest_task_id is used to keep track of the most recent task. Previous tasks are revoked if they are still running or pending.
